# Devise Google oauth authentication failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I started getting this error after updating my rails app and all the gems to the most current versions and cant figure out whats causing it:

```
ERROR -- omniauth: (google_oauth2) Authentication failure! csrf_detected: OmniAuth::Strategies::OAuth2::CallbackError, csrf_detected | CSRF detected
```

First heres the initializer in devise.rb:

```
config.omniauth :google_oauth2, ENV['GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID'], ENV['GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET'],
  { access_type: 'offline', 
    prompt: 'consent',
    select_account: true,
    scope: 'userinfo.email,userinfo.profile',
    client_options: {ssl: {ca_file: Rails.root.join("cacert.pem").to_s}}
  }
```

User.rb has this:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable, 
       :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
       :omniauthable, omniauth_providers: [:google_oauth2, :facebook]
  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    identity = Identity.find_for_oauth(auth)
    if identity.nil?
      identity = Identity.create_with_oauth(auth)
    end
    if identity.user.present?
        return identity.user
    else
        registered_user = User.find_or_create_by(email: auth[:info][:email])
        if registered_user && auth[:provider] == "google_oauth2"
        registered_user.firstname = auth[:info][:first_name] if registered_user.firstname.blank?
        registered_user.lastname = auth[:info][:last_name] if registered_user.lastname.blank?
        registered_user.displayname = auth[:info][:name] if registered_user.displayname.blank?
        registered_user.avatar_remote_url = auth[:info][:image] if registered_user.avatar_data.blank?
        identity.user = registered_user
        identity.save
        registered_user.skip_confirmation!
        registered_user.avatar_remote_url = auth[:info][:image]
        registered_user.save
            return registered_user
        end
    end
  end
```

The Callback controller

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  # You should configure your model like this:
  # devise :omniauthable, omniauth_providers: [:twitter]

  # You should also create an action method in this controller like this:
  def google_oauth2
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
    if @user
      sign_in @user
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      redirect_to new_user_session_path, notice: 'Access Denied.'
    end
  end
```

Ive tried searching for an answer but nothing fits the same and has worked

Comment: This might help [link](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth-oauth2/issues/58)

Comment: I think in Omniauth2 `provider_ignores_state` does not set as default true